# Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'x' of undefined-Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google MAP API in Web Page with the following code.

Web Page have two fields address,geolocation fields.
Enter an address and an on change event will update the map
with the address. A marker will be placed at the address.
If the user needs to move the marker, they can and the geolocation
field will be automatically updated.

I then get this error,When I run this code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined     at Av (common.js:150)
```

And Here is the Javascript Code:

```
 function googleMapAdmin() {

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var map;
        var marker;

        var self = {
            initialize: function() {
                var lat = 0;
                var lng = 0;
                var zoom = 2;
                // set up initial map to be world view. also, add change
                // event so changing address will update the map
                existinglocation = self.getExistingLocation();
                if (existinglocation) {
                    lat = existinglocation[0];
                    lng = existinglocation[1];
                    zoom = 18;
                }

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                var myOptions = {
                  zoom: zoom,
                  center: latlng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                if (existinglocation) {
                    self.setMarker(latlng);
                }

                $("#id_address").change(function() {self.codeAddress();});
            },

            getExistingLocation: function() {
                var geolocation = $("#id_geolocation").val();
                if (geolocation) {
                    return geolocation.split(',');
                }
            },

            codeAddress: function() {
                var address = $("#id_address").val();
                geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                        map.setCenter(latlng);
                        map.setZoom(18);

                        self.setMarker(latlng);
                        self.updateGeolocation(latlng);
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            },

            setMarker: function(latlng) {
                if (marker) {
                    self.updateMarker(latlng);
                } else {
                    self.addMarker({'latlng': latlng, 'draggable': true});
                }
            },

            addMarker: function(Options) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: Options.latlng
                });

                var draggable = Options.draggable || false;
                if (draggable) {
                    self.addMarkerDrag(marker);
                }
            },

            addMarkerDrag: function() {
                marker.setDraggable(true);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(new_location) {
                    self.updateGeolocation(new_location.latLng);
                });
            },

            updateMarker: function(latlng) {
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
            },

            updateGeolocation: function(latlng) {
                $("#id_geolocation")
                    .val(latlng.lat() + "," + latlng.lng())
                    .trigger('change');
            }
        }

        return self;
    }
```

And Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="form-row field-middle_name" style="padding-bottom: 28px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div>
                    <label for="id_middle_name">Search Address:</label>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="id_address" >
                      </div>    

            </div>

    </div>


    <div class="map_canvas_wrapper">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>





    <div class="form-row field-middle_name">
            <div>
                    <label for="id_middle_name">Geolocation:</label>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="geolocation" id="id_geolocation">
                      </div>    

            </div>

    </div>
```

And here is the CSS Code:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#id_address {width: 40em;}
.map_canvas_wrapper {margin-left: 106px;}
#map_canvas {width: 100%; height: 40em;}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have any other errors in your console? and is the javascript you posted from common.js as per the error, and if so, which line is 150?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at Av (common.js:150)
    at _.sv._.k.Ii (common.js:205)
    at Object._.x.trigger (js?key={{api-key}}:104)
    at ay (map.js:14)
    at Zx._.k.fe (map.js:45)
    at Object._.x.trigger (js?key={{api-key}:104)
    at Qv (common.js:160)
    at _.Pv.F (common.js:215)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (js?key={api-key}:36)

Comment: Make sure your HTML loads **before** your map javascript. Otherwise Google maps JS cannot find `#map_canvas`.  So add your javascript in the footer

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.  Just running the code posted "works", I don't see the reported error.